# Sum of unbalanced Dyck words

Tags: combinatorics

I know that Dyck words are related to Catalan numbers, they actually count the Dyck words with equal number of X's and Y's.

I need to compute the cardinality of the set of strings of length k of X's and Y's such that no initial substring contains more Y's than X's. Ie. Like Dyck words but without specifying the total number of X's and Y's, but instead requiring that the sum of X's and Y's equals an integer k.

Any clever idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I am assuming xxyyy, xyxyy, xyyxx etc. are invalid and xyxyx, xxxyy, xxyyx etc. are valid)

We may define a recurrence relation

\begin{align*}
f(m,n)=\begin{cases}
 & 1 &\text{ if } m>=0, n=0 \\ 
 & 0 &\text{ if } m=0, n>0 \lor m<n\\ 
 & f(m-1,n)+f(m,n-1)&\text{ if } m>=n, m>0, n>0 
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Then evaluate 
\begin{align*}
  S(k) &= \sum_{i=0}^k f(k-i,i)
\end{align*}

From OEIS, we find that the sequence is [A001405](https://oeis.org/A001405)

Thus
\begin{align*}
   S(k) &=  \binom{k}{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor}
\end{align*}

***Update***

We can get the enumeration using Chomsky-Schützenberger theorem, refer [Gruber, Lee & Shallit](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.4982)

To summarize,

the grammar that generates the words is

\begin{align*}
  S &\to B \;|\; U \\
  B &\to x\, B\, y\, B\; |\; \epsilon \\   
  U &\to x\,  S \;| \;x\, B\, y\, U \\
\end{align*}

and we form the following formal power series
\begin{align*}
  S(z) &= B(z) + U(z)\\
  B(z) &= B(z)^2 z^2  + 1\\
  U(z) &= S(z) z + B(z) U(z) z^2\\
  \implies S(z) &= \frac{-1+2\,z+\sqrt{1-4\,z^2}}{2\,z-4\,z^2}
\end{align*}

and to answer the question, we need to find $[z^k]S(z)$, which is $\dbinom{k}{\lfloor k/2\rfloor}$

Comment: Thanks. Could you provide a proof

Comment: You're welcome, updated my answer with a link to the paper.